# Share message from Android Wear 2.0 App via Telegram

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, telegram, sony-smartwatch

For sharing messages from my smartwatch app via Telegram standard approach with Intent doesn't work. Current code

```
> final String appName = "org.telegram.messenger";
>             final boolean isAppInstalled = isAppAvailable(this.getApplicationContext(), appName);
>             if (isAppInstalled)
>             {
>                 Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
>                 myIntent.setType("text/plain");
>                 myIntent.setPackage(appName);
>                 myIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "text promo");//
>                 this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(myIntent, "Share with"));
>             }
>             else
>             {
>                 Toast.makeText(this, "Telegram not Installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>             }
```

is ending this nothing - smartwatch doesn't find app of Telegram on smartwatch and do not initiate message sharing.

Why it's happening? Package org.telegram.messenger is not valid for Intent on smart watches?

Thank you for advices and help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After huge research and many tryings i can say, that Android wear app doesn't support any sharings with Telegram. Intent mechanis, doesn't work for 3-d party app in Android Wear.